# Finding the year in another table in Excel when the value isn't the same

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016

I have two tables. I would like to get the data from Blue to the Orange table with following steps:

1. The first column of Orange table has both positive and negative values as percentage, and I need to look for these in Blue table but as absolute value.
2. If the positive value in the Orange table is equal to the absolute value in the Blue table, I supposed to get the year in the same row, and copy it to the Orange table in the adjacent column.

I prefer not to have to change the structure of the tables.

Orange Table:

[image]

Blue Table:

[image]

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Sorry Simona, your question is incomprehensible to me. I think you are asking how to match a value (eg. 11.1%) between two tables, but you may be asking how to get the correct match when there is more than one possible result. Either way if you could clarify the question and provide the table formatting it may get answered.

Comment: I will try to clarify myself.
I have values in 'Years' table:

11.7% 2007
11.5% 2013
12.4%      2010
11.1% #N/A

My goal is to find the 11.1% in another table which her name is 'Employment' and taking the year of that percent. But this value is performance as a -11.1% in 'Employment' table (My goal is not to change the data in percent)

-12.4%       2010
-11.1%       2008
11.7%        2007
11.5%        2013

Thanks for helping :)

Comment: I added pictures also as your request

Comment: Still not clear to me what you want in the end and add all info to your question not to the comments.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you just want to match "-11.1%" to "11.1%"。

You can use the “vlookup” function and then use the "ABS" function in it.

ABS: Get absolute value

You can refer to the following formula:

```
=VLOOKUP(D3,ABS(A3:B4),2,FALSE)
```

[image]

Comment: Correctly what I am meaning for. But, the abs doesnt work in the function. I recieve an error of #Value

Comment: Could you provide a sample of the formula you use?In my tests, I can use it normally.

Comment: I  did this function
=INDEX(EMPLOYMENT!$A$2:$H$97,MATCH($E24,ABS(EMPLOYMENT!$H$2:$H$97),0),2)

After your answer I also did
=VLOOKUP(E28,ABS(EMPLOYMENT!$A$2:$E$97),2,0)

And still doesnt work unfortunately.

Comment: I don't have your source data to help you completely test it. In my simple example, ABS works well. You should make sure that the range you select does not contain empty fields

Comment: Is there another function instead of abs?
Also, I checked and I dont have an empty fields.

Comment: As far as I know, the absolute value formula used directly is only "ABS".

Comment: I also get ```#VALUE!``` for the formula you show in your image with the data you show in your image (Excel 2013).